# On highcharts drilldown, how to know which column that have been clicked

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, click

On highcharts column drilldown, how to know which column that have been clicked?

Comment: what have you done so far ...

Comment: Use `chart.events.drilldown` event, where you have access to the point/points/category, see more info in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown).